# Packaging: Enable universe from an Ubuntu .deb package

Tags: ppa, deb, packaging

I'm constructing a debian .deb package for my application and distributing it through a PPA. If someone follows the PPA instructions verbatim, they get an error message stating that "Some packages could not be installed", giving the missing dependencies that are in universe.

Is there a way to designate a dependency on the universe repository in the .deb or in the PPA, so that the user doesn't have to guess what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, No, there is no such feature. And user should do it by him/herself. However, I am not aware if the new software center has such feature because if may have it own indexes (APT don't download lists from non active repositories).

I would give two possible options:

- Put a note in the package description about it.
- Make them optional, and put note for user in its launcher that tool requires some packages from `universe` to whatever features.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install ...
  ```

  You could go far and include these commands without `sudo` in a script or as an option in your tool, that user can find and quick to run it.